Probability to end up same location on grid
I was given this question during an interview and don't know how to approach it. Consider a 5 by 5 grid. Alice starts at the bottom left corner. Bob starts at the upper right corner.
Every second, Alice will randomly move one edge to the right or one edge up with equal probability. At the same time, Bob will randomly move either one edge to the left or one edge down. Each person must move each second.
What is the probability that Alice and Bob share the same position at some point? $ {}$
I really don't know how to approach this problem, maybe conditional probability suffices where we condition on Alice's position but not sure. Thank you so much for any help!

I would try to answer the sub-questions: At what time might they meet?  Where might they meet?  What is the probability that they meet at each of those places? What is the total probability that they meet?

There is a slight shortcut that avoids the addition in finding the total probability, but I suspect that it is harder to spot than doing the sub-questions.

In this problem, does a $5$ by $5$ grid refer to $5$ dots by $5$ dots, or $5$ squares by $5$ squares?

5 squares by 5 squares

Conditional probability ? No, no, no.  The sub-questions suggested by Henry are really good. At what time might they meet? Where might they meet? Those 2 questions are easy. After, it is more complex.

I don't really know what's meant with dots or squares. Surely the plain interpretation must be that a 5x5 grid has 5 positions on a side and 25 positions total, rather than 6 positions on a side and 36 total positions? The discussion of corners and edges confuses things a little.

Alice and Bob can only meet along the diagonal of the $N$x$N$ square after $N-1$ steps. Each person's position on the diagonal is distributed according to the binomial distribution, in this case ranging from $0$ to $N-1$ according to $B(N-1, 0.5)$. The chance they meet anywhere is the sum of the probabilities that they both occupy any particular square together.
The probability that they meet on an $N$x$N$ grid is $ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f(k, N-1, 0.5) ^2 $, where $f(k,n,p)$ is the binomial probability mass function.
For $N=5$, this works out to a $27\%$ probability. As $N$ increases, the number of possible meeting places increases, and the probability that both Alice and Bob randomly happen to arrive at the same one decreases.

I suspect there is something amiss in your formula. Why $N-1$ ? I suspect you have mixed up "dots" and "squares"

@trueblueanil: It's possible Nuclear Hoagie has missed the comment by OP where they clarify that it's squares vs dots.

@BrianTung: Quite likely, but hopefully NH will see in due course !

@trueblueanil On an NxN grid, the diagonal position gets indexed between 0 and N-1. There are only 4 steps to get to the diagonal on a 5x5 grid, the position basically counts the number of successful coin flips. The number of transitions is one less than the number of squares. Summing the formula from k=0 up to N instead of N-1 would allow six possibilities for where Alice and Bob could meet, but there are only five diagonal squares.

@trueblueanil I don't really know what that means. I don't know why we'd interpret a "5x5 grid" not to be a grid of valid positions, but the grid of spaces in between valid positions, but I guess either is possible. As I interpret it, a 5x5 grid encodes 25 valid positions, not 36.

Ok, with your interpretation, $N-1$ would be correct, I can't find a definitive definition for a grid, though for a matrix there is no ambiguity. I went by OP's clarification. Good day !

However, in puzzles like how many squares are there in a 3x3 grid, the smaller squares are always taken to be 9

And finally, my conclusion (for what it is worth) is that grid is synonymous with matrix. Would you say that a 2x2 grid means a single square ?

@trueblueanil No, a 2x2 grid or matrix is a table with 2 rows and 2 columns. The digits denote the number of positions in each row or column. I think we agree that a 2x2 grid or matrix has 4 positions - a 2x2 matrix in mathematical terms definitely does not have 9 cells. Interpreting a 5x5 grid as having 6 cells on a side is very strange.

Oh, you are taking that they move from centre of one square to another, whereas I took NE Lattice paths https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path from (0,0) to (5,5) for Alice Anyway, our answers are ok for the differing interpretations, and the question is now closed. Cheers ! $;;$ :)

Here is an attempt in a less technical way for this $\texttt{particular problem}$
$\textbf{(But extended later to a general formula in the P.S.)}$
To illustrate a point I first take a $3\times 3$ square, showing how we can count number of paths Alice can take from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$ by building up line by line from line $0$ upwards which shows how many ways exist to go from $(0,0)$ to any point by simple addition.
Note that the final result,$\;20$ = $\dfrac{6!}{3!3!}$, as expected
Line $3:\;\; 1-4-10-20$
Line $2:\;\; 1-3-6-10$
Line $1:\;\; 1=2-3-4$
Line $0:\;\; 0-1-1-1$
Also note that the diagonal $1-3-3-1$ here, and if you work out similarly for a $5\times5$ square, $1-5-10-10-5-1$
With the preliminaries out of the way, it should be clear by symmetry, that Alice and Bob can meet $\mathtt{simultaneously}$ in $5$ steps $\mathtt{only}$ on the diagonal in $(1^2 +5^2+10^2+10^2+5^2+1^2) = 252$ ways against $2^5*2^5$ total choices they have in $5$ steps
$$\texttt{Thus finally,} Pr = \dfrac{252}{2^{10}} = \dfrac{63}{256}, \approx 24.6\%$$
PS:
With a bit more time to think, and noticing the central binomial coefficient appearing in the solution , the $\texttt{general formula}$ for a $n\times n$$\;\; \texttt{square}$ can be written as
$$Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{4^n}$$
